# Cordova Reactjs IOS app api call 403 error

Tags: ios, reactjs, cordova

I am developing a Hybrid application using reacts, cordova for iOS and android.
My Android application working as expected with same code but iOS app is giving 403 error while trying call api.

**Below is the error for IOS - **
{"message":"Request failed with status code
403","name":"Error", "stack" :"@file:///
Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/ CoreSimulator/Devices/
007E24CA-4FA4-4E78-8245-
C896E6BBCE1F/data/Containers/ Bundle/Application/
6C093D41-0D16-47BB-88B4-83367A
CDCEE1/MYAPP.app/www/static/js/ 3.89b40661.chunk.js:2:783297\n@file:
///Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/ CoreSimulator/Devices/
007E24CA-4FA4-4E78-8245-
C896E6BBCE1F/data/Containers/ Bundle/Application/
6C093D41-0D16-47BB-88B4-83367A
CDCEE1/MYAPP.app/www/static/js/

I am using below library for app development -
Cordova 9
Cordova-ios : 5.1.1

**Plugins** :
"@ahovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix": "^1.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "^1.2.2",

if anyone can just guide me it will be great help. Thanks in advance.

initially I was getting network error -

ERROR - {"message":"Network
Error" "name":"Error" "stack":"@file:///
Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/ CoreSimulator/Devices/136869FE-
F58B-45B9-915B-2F9881D6A3DE/ data/Containers/Bundle/Application/
CD1861AF-A6EB-42F7-9071-2F13BED2F8C5/

I googled it and experts suggested to install cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix plugin and after installed above plugin , Network issue got resolved but I am getting 403 error.

Now struggling to fix this 403 error.